# Given the Newton constant $G$, the speed of light $c$ and the Planck constant $h$, construct an energy of the system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants, absolute-units

How do I use dimensional analysis to construct an energy for the system given the Newton constant $G$, the speed of light $c$ and the Planck constant $h$? I don't know of any energy formulas containing the constants $G$, $c$ and $h$.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but you might want to check out proposals for [defining the kilogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilogram#Proposed_future_definitions) along with the Watt balance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: See [Planck energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_energy).

Answer (score 1):

"I don't know any equations..." is the *point* of dimensional analysis!

Let's make a table of the quantities you listed, and their dimensions:

```
    M   L   T
G  -1   3  -2  \
c       1  -1   +- given these inputs...
h   1   2  -1  /
-------------
E   1   2  -2  - I need to get this output
```

If we assume there is an expression

$$E \propto G^A c^B h^C$$

then it follows that we need to solve for A, B, C such that

```
 -A +       C =  1  (balancing M)
 3A +  B + 2C =  2  (balancing L)
-2A -  B -  C = -2  (balancing T)
```

I will leave you the fun of solving for A, B and C - the coefficients will be non-integer.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Say,[image]

This implies
m=-1/2
n=1/2
p=5/2

So this way you can formulate equations by dimensional analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Write down a few dimensionally correct equations. E.g.:

$$E = m c^2$$

$$E = m^2 G/r$$

$$E = h f = h c/r$$

Divide the last two:

$$1 = m^2 G/(h c)$$

So, we have that:

$$m = \sqrt{\frac{h c}{G}}$$

Therefore:

$$E = m c^2 = c^{\frac{5}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{h}{G}}$$

Comment: This looks odd. $$E=mc^2$$ refers to the energy of a massive particle. $$E = hf$$ refers to the energy of a massless particle with a wavelength $r$. $$E=\frac{m^2G}{r}$$ refers to the energy of a system of two massive particles with a separation of $r$. Three different systems, the way I see it.

Comment: @Alec, as we're only interested in the dimensions, we can do the computations modulo the physics content. Two quantities are considered equivalent if they have the same SI dimensions.